Using Marker Name in Log4j2 RollingFileAppender
I am attempting to use the name of the marker as the filename of a RollingFileAppender, defined inside a RoutingAppender, similar to this example except with <RolingFile> instead of <File>. The eventual purpose of this is per-user logging in the application. The marker is the username.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get this error:
2024-12-20T14:59:14.322023700Z userTaskScheduler-2 ERROR Unable to create file \app\logs/${event:Marker}.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:463)
        at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)
        at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:651)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:863)

Here's the log4j2 setup:
<Properties>
    <Property name="basePath" value="\app\logs" />
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Routing name="ROUTING">
        <Routes pattern="$${event:Marker}">
            <!--<Route key="DEFAULT" ref="FILE"/>-->
            <Route>
                <RollingFile
                    name="${event:Marker}"
                    fileName="${basePath}/${event:Marker}.log"
                    filePattern="${basePath}/${event:Marker}_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz" 
                    append="true">


                    <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %X{username} | [%marker] | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
                    <Policies>
                        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                    </Policies>
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
</Appenders>

Here's the Java code:
public class LoggingServiceImpl implements LoggingService {
    
    private Map<String, Marker> monitoredUsersMarkers;
    private Marker DEFAULT = MarkerFactory.getMarker("DEFAULT");

    // code to populate markers map

    @Override
    public Marker getMarker(String userId) {
        
        Marker result = monitoredUsersMarkers.getOrDefault(userId, DEFAULT);
        return result;
    }

I've researched and looked at previous questions but they didn't solve my problem.

Would whoever downvoted my question care to comment on what was wrong with it?

You configuration doesn't cover the case, when a log event has no marker. If no marker is present the ${event:Marker} placeholder is not expanded and causes the error you are seeing.
To prevent this problem the example you are citing uses a placeholder with a default value ${event:Marker:-main}, which expands to "main" if no marker is present. See Property Substitution for more details.
To solve your problem you can either:

Add a default value to most ${event:Marker} expansions:
<RollingFile name="${event:Marker}"
             fileName="${basePath}/${event:Marker:-main}.log"
             filePattern="${basePath}/${event:Marker:-main}_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz">
  ...
</RollingFile>


Or add an additional route for the literal key "${event:Marker}". You need to escape it using $$ to prevent expansion:
<!--
  ~ If no marker is present use the appender named `FILE`
  ~ from the `<Appenders>` container
  -->
<Route key="$${event:Marker}" ref="FILE"/>
<!-- Default route -->
<Route>
  <RollingFile name="${event:Marker}"
               fileName="${basePath}/${event:Marker}.log"
               filePattern="${basePath}/${event:Marker}_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz">
    ...
  </RollingFile>
</Route>




That seemed to work, thank you. But followup question: can I use a constant value for a route,i.e.: <Route key="AUTH" ref="AUTH" /> along with the configuration you created? AUTH would be a separately created Appender.

Sure, you can mix up appender definitions and appender references. The routing appender basically evaluates the pattern and tries to find a route definition with the appropriate key attribute. If there is no such definition, it falls back to the route without a key attribute.

I've accepted your answer. Unfortunately, I could make it work with FileAppender, but not RollingFileAppender. Thank you for your help.

You can run your application with -Dlog4j2.debug to see how the configuration is interpreted.
